# Trying to get property 'CODIGO' of non-object

Tags: laravel

Olá,
Estou desesperado. Um trecho de código que sempre funcionou parou e não funciona por nada.

```
    $turnos = DB::table('TURNOS')
                            ->where('SIGLA', '=', $sigla)
                            ->first();
    
    $codigo = $turnos->CODIGO; // DÁ ERRO NESTA LINHA: ErrorException
```

Trying to get property 'CODIGO' of non-object

```
Mas, se eu der um dd(), os dados aparecem!!!!!
```

{#4663 ▼
+"CODIGO": 2
+"DESCRICAO": "TARDE"
+"SIGLA": "T"
}

Por favor, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Falta dados pra te ajudar, primeiramente, o que você está dando dd()? Pois este erro de "trying to get property", acontece porque o $turnos está retornando nulo, ou seja, ele não pode apontar para uma outra variável se ele mesmo não existir. verifique o que ele está retornando na variável $turnos, se é nulo ou não

Answer (score -2):

No seu `dd()` pode estar retornando um Objeto sim, mas no momento que está rodando certamente esse objeto vem nulo, ou seja, a consulta não retorna nada.
Falta um pouco de informação pra conseguir te ajudar melhor, mas a princípio é que realmente o Query Builder não está encontrando nenhum registro, sua select não retorna nada.